# what is the usage of the SessionStore in the isAuthorized method in pac4j 5.3.1

Tags: java, authorization, java-17, pac4j, wildfly-26

I'm getting **403 forbidden** error for the external requests.
And found the authorization is failing from the **isAuthorized** method inside the  **CsrfAuthorizer.class** which is derived from pac4j.

And I compared the pack4j version 4.3.1, the isAuthorized method is pretty much different in the 4.3.1.
Here is the two methods in the different versions.

VERSION 4.3.1

```
     boolean checkRequest = this.checkAllRequests || ContextHelper.isPost(context) || ContextHelper.isPut(context) || ContextHelper.isPatch(context) || ContextHelper.isDelete(context);
     if (!checkRequest) {
         return true;
     } else {
         String parameterToken = (String)context.getRequestParameter(this.parameterName).orElse((Object)null);
         String headerToken = (String)context.getRequestHeader(this.headerName).orElse((Object)null);
         Optional<String> sessionToken = context.getSessionStore().get(context, "pac4jCsrfToken");
         return sessionToken.isPresent() && (((String)sessionToken.get()).equals(parameterToken) || ((String)sessionToken.get()).equals(headerToken));
     }
 }
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
VERSION 5.3.1
 
     public boolean isAuthorized(final WebContext context, final SessionStore sessionStore, final List<UserProfile> profiles) {
     final var checkRequest = checkAllRequests || isPost(context) || isPut(context) || isPatch(context) || isDelete(context);
     if (checkRequest) {
         final var parameterToken = context.getRequestParameter(parameterName).orElse(null);
         final var headerToken = context.getRequestHeader(headerName).orElse(null);
         LOGGER.debug("parameterToken: {}", parameterToken);
         LOGGER.debug("headerToken: {}", headerToken);
         final var sessionPreviousToken = sessionStore.get(context, Pac4jConstants.PREVIOUS_CSRF_TOKEN);
         final var sessionToken = sessionStore.get(context, Pac4jConstants.CSRF_TOKEN);
         final var sessionDate = sessionStore.get(context, Pac4jConstants.CSRF_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_DATE);
         if (sessionStore.getSessionId(context, false).isPresent()) {
             sessionStore.set(context, Pac4jConstants.PREVIOUS_CSRF_TOKEN, null);
         }
         // all checks are always performed, conditional operations are turned into logical ones,
         // string comparisons are replaced by hash equalities to be protected against time-based attacks
         final var hasSessionData = sessionToken.isPresent() & sessionDate.isPresent();
         final var previousToken = (String) sessionPreviousToken.orElse("");
         LOGGER.debug("previous token: {}", previousToken);
         final var token = (String) sessionToken.orElse("");
         LOGGER.debug("token: {}", token);
         final var isGoodCurrentToken = hashEquals(token, parameterToken) | hashEquals(token, headerToken);
         final var isGoodPreviousToken = hashEquals(previousToken, parameterToken) | hashEquals(previousToken, headerToken);
         final var isGoodToken = isGoodCurrentToken | isGoodPreviousToken;
         final var expirationDate = (Long) sessionDate.orElse(0L);
         final var now = new Date().getTime();
         final var isDateExpired = expirationDate < now;
         if (!hasSessionData | !isGoodToken | isDateExpired) {
             return false;
         }

     }
     return true;
 }
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         final var isGoodCurrentToken = hashEquals(token, parameterToken) | hashEquals(token, headerToken);
         final var isGoodPreviousToken = hashEquals(previousToken, parameterToken) | hashEquals(previousToken, headerToken);
         final var isGoodToken = isGoodCurrentToken | isGoodPreviousToken;
         final var expirationDate = (Long) sessionDate.orElse(0L);
         final var now = new Date().getTime();
         final var isDateExpired = expirationDate < now;
         if (!hasSessionData | !isGoodToken | isDateExpired) {
             return false;
         }

All of above are false.
So then it returns false always.

Does anyone has a clear idea about the usage of this?
```